# Tkinter GUI widgets hanging (Inputs are sent continuously over hyperlink/serial)

Tags: python-3.x, user-interface, tkinter

```
    from tkinter import *
    from serial import Serial
    import sys
    import binascii
    from queue import Queue
    import time





    ser = Serial('COM3', 9600, timeout=1)
```

Taking Serial Inputs through USB
read is made global so it can be accessed in update_reading function

```
    global read
    reading = ser.read(8).hex()  
    read=reading



    root=Tk()
    root.geometry('500x500')
    root.configure(bg='#ffffff')
```

TextBox is created so that solution can be placed there

```
    e=Entry(root,width=35,borderwidth=5)
    e.grid(row=0, column=0,columnspan=3,padx=10,pady=10)
```

Update to the next serial value

```
    def update_reading():    
        b=ser.read(8).hex()

        if read==b: 

            update_reading()
        else:

            reading=a
            button_click(a)


    def button_click(read):
        e.delete(0,END) 
        e.insert(0,read)
        update_reading()
```

when button is clicked it prints the value on text box

```
    myButton=Button(root,text="Output Values",command=lambda:button_click(reading))
    myButton.grid(row=0,column=5,padx=10,pady=0)


    root.mainloop()
```

Comment: if some code runs all time then it blocks `mainloop` which updates/redraw widgets in windows. You may have to run code in separated thread or use `root.after` to repeate function periodically and then mainloop has time to update/redraw widgets. Or you have to use periodically `root.update()` to manually update/redraw widgets.